# How can I validate if the private and public VAPID keys are the right pair?

Tags: security, npm, vapid

After running

```
npm install -g web-push
web-push generate-vapid-keys
```

It generates a public and private key. Given the two keys, is there any way to verify if they're the right pair? (ie if I have the private key and I might have mistyped the public key) but want to make sure its's correct